# Java: Failed to write an ArrayList<Long> to text file

Tags: java, arraylist, io

I defined `size_list` as an ArrayList of `Long`. I did `import java.io.*;` already. Somehow, the following still gave me an error. I was doing the same thing as other posts I came across. Does anyone what went wrong ?

```
    ArrayList<Long> size_list = some_method();
    try{
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("results.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        for(int i = 0; i < size_list.size(); i++ ){
            out.write(size_list.get(i));
            out.newline();
        }
        out.close();
    } catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error writing to file " );
    }
```

The error messages I got:

```
 no suitable method found for write(Long)
                out.write(size_list.get(i));
                   ^
    method Writer.write(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Long cannot be converted to int)
    method Writer.write(char[]) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Long cannot be converted to char[])
    method Writer.write(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Long cannot be converted to String)
    method BufferedWriter.write(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Long cannot be converted to int)
SCCsAlgo.java:287: error: cannot find symbol
                out.newline();
                   ^
  symbol:   method newline()
  location: variable out of type BufferedWriter
```

Comment: These errors should be caught during compilation itself. Better use a good IDE for your coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out.write(size_list.get(i).toString());
out.newLine();
```

instead of

```
out.write(size_list.get(i));
out.newline();
```

Java is `Case sensitive`. So no more method for writing Long in `BufferedWriter` and also no method like `newline()`;

Comment: sorry, I don't understand why case sensitive makes the `write Long` method and `newline()` method go away.

Comment: You are able to write on String not Long, int, etc... In you code you use out.newline() but in BufferedWriter class no method named as newline. But mentioned the l as small character so it wont accept. Thats why i mentioned it as case sensitive. In java method names must be starts with small char and after the joing words should be Caps. ex: newLine, excelSheetPreparation, etc....

Comment: you are having List as Long not a String. so if you get any values from the list it only gives Long value. So you cant write the long value in your BufferedWriter.

Comment: But why is there nor a  write Long method ?

Comment: For your clarification BufferedWriter allowable methods to visit the link for BufferedWriter Class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(char[])

Comment: I guess I can also cast long to int and write them to a text file, according to the documentation.

Comment: But possible lossy conversion from long to int.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have method like

```
 BufferedWriter.write(Long);
```

Instead of this you could convert it into String and write it like:

```
out.write(size_list.get(i).toString() + "\n");
```

You could get rid of newline (you have type there you should have used newLine note L in caps) method as well.